# Call function with empty variadic param

Tags: swift

I have a function with one variadic param (tuple) like this:

```
func conditions<T>(conditions: ([String : T], LogicalOperator)...) -> [AnyObject]?
```

Is there any way how to call it without that param? Somehow pass an empty array of variadic params? I just want to be able to support an option when there are no conditions at all.

Comment: make it optional or assign a default value ?

Comment: Generally you can call a function (which takes a variable number of arguments) without arguments. The problem here is that without arguments the compiler cannot infer the generic type `T`.

Comment: Well, here we go, Martin explained it well.

Comment: @sunshine: That does not mean that you have to delete your answer :) It is my "problem" if  I write a comment only.

Comment: Thanks Martin for making this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but not as a generic function. Why? Because it can't infer the type, so the compiler doesn't know what T is, even tho your tuple will be optional. So code below in theory would work, but the execution will fall:

```
struct Test<T> {
    func conditions<T>(conditions: ([String : T], String)?...) -> [AnyObject]? {
        return nil
    }
}

var t = Test<Int>()
t.conditions() // Error infering type
```

However, this one does work (if it does satisfy your needs):

```
struct Test<T> {
    typealias testAlias = ([String : T], String)
    func conditions(conditions: testAlias...) -> [AnyObject]? {
        return nil
    }
}

var t = Test<Int>()
t.conditions()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism).

You could overload your function definition to accept no arguments...

- `func conditions() -> [AnyObject]?`

or, you could overload it to accept an array of your type...

- `func conditions<T>(conditions: [([String : T], LogicalOperator)]) -> [AnyObject]?`

or you could make it accept optional values and pass nil.

- `func conditions<T>(conditions: ([String : T], LogicalOperator)?...) -> [AnyObject]?`

Comment: `func conditions<T>() -> [AnyObject]?` does not compile.

Comment: Thanks for throwing some ideas. +1